# How to reply on telephone conversation

Tags: conversation, telephone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to answer to 'Is this John?' on phone?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56295/how-to-answer-to-is-this-john-on-phone)

When I get a call from some sales agents/shops and they ask, 'Am I speaking with Akpa?' should I just say 'Yes,' or 'yes, speaking '...or what?