# How to answer to "I'd like to speak to John" on telephone?

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english, sentence

This question is close to but not the same as: [How to answer “Is this John?” on phone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56295/how-to-answer-is-this-john-on-phone)

If someone calls me and asks: "I'd like to talk to John", how should I answer to sound natural?

```
- This is John speaking.
- It's he/him.
- It's me.
```

Is there any better option?

Edit 1: English is not my mother tongue, so the my question is legitimate since I am asking how people usually answer to a question like this on the phone because I wouldn't know how to do it properly.

Comment: There is advice hereabouts that transcends the grammatical and even the idiomatic: _Find out who wants to know before you give away **any** information._

Comment: How is this question 'opinion-based' and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56295/how-to-answer-is-this-john-on-phone is not?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you've seen that the link on my previous comment was on the question at the time I posted it, right?

Comment: No, I assumed you were correct in your statement that the two questions were sufficiently dissimilar. They're both off-topic as seeking opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the one-word reply "Speaking...".

Comment: Yes, then one needn't venture into troubled waters at all....

Answer (score -1):

If it is someone older ,someone you respect or someone you don’t know:

> This is John speaking.

If it’s your friend or someone younger then you:

> That’s me!

**or**

> It’s me.

It’s he/him is grammatically correct, but it doesn’t sound good. I would recommend ‘I’m him’.

Hope this helped.

Comment: That's me is technically incorrect. That's him, that's her is used to refer to identify a person, in a deictic reference. That's me would be OK for bingo, and exclaiming that you've won. That's me could also be you identifying yourself in a picture....

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I didn’t know that. Any better sentences? @Lambie

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I’d opt for 
"That would be me. How can I help you?"
The alternatives of "this is he" and "that’s me" sound too formal or not quite formal enough, respectively.

I might also use "That would be myself" because "me" is a short word which is easily misheard on a phone line. Sometimes it’s less about grammar and more about communicating effectively and making people feel at ease.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: One can also say: This is Pam, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: What could ***me*** be misheard as?